# What is the maximum length of sequence where the sum of 5 consecutive numbers in positive and sum of 8 consecutive numbers is negatve

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

What can be maximum length of such sequence?

Hint one such sequence is

> -21,0,10,10,10,10,0,-21

Comment: Is this your own puzzle, or from somewhere else (i.e. a competition or the internet)? For all non-original puzzles we require acknowledgement and/or a link.

Comment: I was asked this question by a friend who in-turn was asked in an interview. So a bit difficult to find the link

Comment: The sum of _any_ 5/8 consecutive numbers, or the sum of _every_ 5/8 consecutive numbers?

Comment: @IanMacDonald What is the difference between the two things you said?

Comment: This is a variant of [IMO 1977 problem 2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3804_1977_imo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the length of the longest such sequence is

> $11$

Proof of upper bound

> Suppose we have such a sequence of length $12$ say $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{12}$.
>  By comparing the sums $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7 + a_8$ and $a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7 + a_8$ we see that $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 < 0$. By increasing the indices  incrementally by one each time we can see that we also have $a_2 + a_3 + a_4 < 0$, $a_3 + a_4 + a_5 < 0$, $a_4 + a_5 + a_6 < 0$ and $a_5 + a_6 + a_7 < 0$.
>  Similarly, by comparing the sums $a_5 + a_6 + a_7 + a_8 + a_9 + a_{10} + a_{11} + a_{12}$ and $a_5 + a_6 + a_7 + a_8 + a_9$, we see that $a_{10} + a_{11} + a_{12} < 0$. By decreasing, the indices incrementally by one each time we can see that we also have $a_9 + a_{10} + a_{11} < 0$, $a_8 + a_9 + a_{10} < 0$, $a_7 + a_8 + a_9 < 0$ and $a_6 + a_7 + a_8 < 0$.
>  Overall, we see that the sum of any three consecutive terms must be negative.
>  Now consider $a_1 + (a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + a_6) = (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) + (a_4 + a_5 + a_6) < 0$.
>  From this we see that $a_1 < 0$. We can increment all the indices by $1$ in the above equation to get $a_2 < 0$ and by continuing this procedure, we find that $a_3, a_4, a_5 < 0$. But $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4  + a_5 > 0$ which is a contradiction.

Proof of lower bound

> Here is a sequence of length $11$ which satisfies the constraints $$ -12, 19, -12, -12, 19, -12, 19, -12, -12, 19, -12  $$

How did I find such a sequence

> Let's say I take my upper bound proof and try to apply to a sequence with length $11$.
>  I quickly find that I am unable to prove that $a_5 + a_6 + a_7 < 0$.
>  The knock-on effect is that I can prove some elements of my sequence are negative but that the elements $a_2, a_5, a_7, a_{10}$ cannot be shown to be negative.
>  So, let's assume that all elements are negative except for these four, which I'll assume to be positive.
>  Then, each group of $5$ consecutive entries contains $3$ negatives and $2$ positives and each group of $8$ consecutive entries contains $5$ negatives and $3$ positives. This means that I can simplify things by setting all positive entries to the same value $X$ and all negative entries to the same value $-Y$.
>  My sequence is then guaranteed to satisfy the constraints as long as $$ 2X - 3Y > 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 3X - 5Y < 0$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{3}{2} Y < X < \frac{5}{3}Y $$ To simplify things, I decided to make $Y$ divisible by $6$ (this is not a necessary step but makes both ends of the inequality integers). I also decided that I wanted to try and make $X$ an integer (also not necessary). Setting $Y=6$ gives $9 < X < 10$, so not an integer.
>  Setting $Y=12$ gives $18 < X < 20$ so $X=19$ works, as required.
>  Note here that there are plenty of other choices for $X$ and $Y$, I just chose these to make the arithmetic nicer.

As Florian F has pointed out in the comments there is a simpler integer choice. Given that

> $$\frac{3}{2} < \frac{3+5}{2+3} = \frac{8}{5} < \frac{5}{3}$$ we can pick $X=8$ and $Y=5$ to generate another valid sequence $$ -5, 8, -5, -5, 8, -5, 8, -5, -5, 8,-5 $$

And pushing this Fibonacci link a bit further we know that

> $$\frac{3}{2} < \phi < \frac{5}{3}$$ which means that another nice valid sequence is $$-1, \phi, -1, -1, \phi, -1, \phi, -1, -1, \phi, -1 $$

Comment: What is the reasoning behind -12 and 19? I mean how did you come up with that?

Comment: @SagarChand I will edit in how I found this sequence.

Comment: Actually the simplest rational between $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{5}{3}$ is $\frac{3+5}{2+3} = \frac{8}{5}$. So you can replace $-12$ by $-5$ and $19$ by $8$.  Aren't these nicer numbers?

Comment: @FlorianF I was thinking recently that you could make $X=\phi$ and $Y=1$ and this also works. I may include both choices in an edit.

Comment: The last one is very beautiful!